# Openvas : Change in port list has unexpected results

Tags: openvas

I have encountered strange results while changing only the port list for some targets.

If I use the wizard (immediate scan) to scan a couple of hosts, I get a report with some medium vulnerabilities. If I clone the target that was created by the wizard and just change the port list to scan all TCP and all UDP, I get a report with only "log level" vulnerabilities.

I may be doing something wrong but I can't figure out what.

Here are the details for the target used by the wizard:

```
Comment:    Automatically generated by wizard
Hosts:  example.com, example.io
Exclude Hosts:  
Reverse Lookup Only:    No
Reverse Lookup Unify:   No
Maximum number of hosts:    2
Port List:  OpenVAS Default
Alive Test:     Scan Config Default
Credentials for authenticated checks:
SSH:    
SMB:    
ESXi:   
SNMP:
```

Here is the target that I modified from a clone of the one above :

```
Comment:    Modified from automatically generated by wizard
Hosts:  example.com, example.io
Exclude Hosts:  
Reverse Lookup Only:    No
Reverse Lookup Unify:   No
Maximum number of hosts:    2
Port List:  All TCP and UDP
Alive Test:     Scan Config Default
Credentials for authenticated checks:
SSH:    
SMB:    
ESXi:   
SNMP:
```

Here is my All TCP and UDP port list :

```
Port List: All TCP and UDP
Comment:    
Port count:     131070
TCP Port count:     65535
UDP Port count:     65535
Port Ranges (2)
Start   End     Protocol
1       65535   tcp
1       65535   udp
```

The score I get for the task created by the wizard is : 6.4 (Medium)

The score I get for the task ran on the cloned target is : 0.0 (Log)

What I am missing ?

AFAICT, I just changed the port list and should, at least, get a score as high as the ones I got with the wizard-created task

How can I create a task that would scan "à la" Wizard using all TCP and UDP ports instead of just the ones used by the Wizard ?

I am using OpenVAS9 in a docker container (mikesplain/openvas) and use GreenBone web-based interface and I had the very same problem on my local Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the target system the port scan of ALL UDP and ALL TCP will take too long to finish, the portscanner will timeout and thus information about the portscan got lost.

Try again with a different portlist with less UDP ports. This can be configured in the GSA when creating a new Target via Configuration -> Targets.

A good start could be either "All TCP and Nmap 5.51 top 1000 UDP" or "All TCP and Nmap 5.51 top 100 UDP".

Disclaimer: NVT Developer @ Greenbone